# Embed a video in Internet Explorer without Flash

Tags: internet-explorer, video, embed

Do I really have to settle with Flash for embedding videos in a web page if I want IE to be able to view it?

Isn't there a way to stick a video on a web page in IE without Flash?

Seriously.

Comment: There are several ways to embed players and plugins. What kind of Video are you talking about?

Comment: Also, why are you limiting this to IE? Just curious.

Comment: Well I'm not limiting to IE. I'm just trying to come up with a solution for the percentage of people who use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are just supporting IE, you can try things like using the `<object>` tag (IE version) to embed video using a plug-in like the Windows Media Player plug-in, which should be ready to use on your client's computers (if you're only supporting IE and Windows).

More info: http://perishablepress.com/press/2007/01/29/embed-flash-and-video-via-the-object-tag/

Comment: great just what i needed

Answer (score 1):

There is no native way to embed a video in a web page in IE before IE 9.

In IE < 9, your choices are to just link to the video, and let your users download it, or to use a plugin. Flash is the most widely supported plugin, but other options include [Silverlight](https://web.archive.org/web/20121030190821/http://www.silverlight.net:80/) or [QuickTime](https://support.apple.com/guide/quicktime-player/welcome/mac).

As of [IE 9](https://web.archive.org/web/20151124012925/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/04/29/html5-video.aspx) (now in [platform preview](https://web.archive.org/web/20150602071950/http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/), soon in beta), IE supports the [HTML5 `<video>` tag](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#video). Apparently, it only supports H.264 at the moment, but it may support other codecs in the future.